# Unity3D - WebGL returning a variable from a web3 call into unity from js

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine, webgl

I'm facing a problem and i'm kinda shamed to be posting something that looks very noobish :D

Context:  I'm doing a small project for WebGL with Unity and i'm struggling to return a variable from a function.

I run that simple script in Unity to call a function that i have in a .jslib file.

```
[DllImport("__Internal")] private static extern string GetBalance(string s);

    public void Start() { 
   
   string s = WalletAddress();
   ButtonText.text = GetTokenBal(s);
  }
```

That's the function i'm calling and i want to return Balance as result of that fun.

Eventually i'm able to console.log that function via browser but i'm not getting anything back into unity. Most likely because this variale takes a while to be available so i guess returning into Start() it's not a correct approach. I guess

```
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("xxxx"));

GetBalance: function (str) {
var addr = (Pointer_stringify(str));
var contractAddr = ('xxxx');
var tknAddress = (addr).substring(2);
var balance = 0;
var contractData = ('0x70a08231000000000000000000000000' + tknAddress);
 

web3.eth.call({
    to: contractAddr, 
    data: contractData 
    }, function(err, result) {
    if (result) { 
        var tokens = web3.utils.toBN(result).toString();
        console.log('Tokens Owned: ' + web3.utils.fromWei(tokens, 'kwei')); 
        balance = web3.utils.fromWei(tokens, 'kwei');
        
    } else {
        console.log(err);
}
    
});

return balance;

  }
```

Pretty much feeling sorry to maybe ask a simple question, but i'm learning so i miss pieces of the puzzle.

If this variable is available at the time i can console.log into the browser. How am i suppsed to send it back to unity to update a variable inside there?
Thx for the patience :)

Answer (score 1):

**Solved**: leaving that knowledge for someone else here:

I created a new function in my `c#` script:

```
public void MyFunction(string s) {
    ButtonText.text = s;
}
```

Then, I changed the function in my `.jslib` to send avoiding return, but directly forwarding the value to the unity instance:

```cs
unityInstance.SendMessage('Text_Balance', 'MyFunction', "Variable I want to pass as argument in MyFunction");
```